# How to compare two lists of type string in java

Tags: java, list

I need to check whether elements of one list or array exists in other list.

The size of lists are same.

Apart from sorting is any simple solution possible?

Comment: [List#contains](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#contains(java.lang.Object)) ?

Comment: Hi Chirag, what you tried? Please paste an example

Comment: [List#containsAll](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#containsAll(java.util.Collection))? (Along the same theme as KevinEsche's comment)

Comment: Hi Chirag, try using `list.contains(elements)`

Comment: @AndyTurner There is a limitation to that solution, see my answer.

Answer (score 2):

You are right in saying that if they are arrays you can't use `Arrays.equals()`, if they are `List<>`s then you cannot just use [equals](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#equals(java.lang.Object)). In both cases they also check order.

So yes your main option without writing your own comparison algorithm is to use `Collections.sort()` on both lists.

If you don't need to check for duplicates you could drop both lists into a `HashSet` using `addAll` and then compare the two `HashSet` or just use [`List.containsAll`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#containsAll(java.util.Collection)). The bad news though is that these would both have the same limitation, if you need to compare lists that might have repeated elements then it may give incorrect results. i.e. "bob", "bob", "fred" would compare as equal to "bob", "fred", "fred".

Comment: The question only ask for a check “*whether* elements of one list or array exists in other list” not for matching number of occurrences, thus, there is no need to handle duplicates specially.

Comment: @Holger Actually the question is unclear, which is why I gave both solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to the example below:

```
public class Example{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        List<String> list1 = new ArrayList<String>();
        List<String> list2 = new ArrayList<String>();

        list1.add("A");
        list1.add("B");
        list1.add("C");

        list2.add("C");
        list2.add("X");
        list2.add("Y");

        for(String s : list1){
            if(list2.contains(s)){
                System.out.println("List 2 contains: " + s);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The code above is by all means not the cleanest or the most compact way to achieve what you are asking. But given the information presented, this should suffice.

Comment: While this may solve his problem depending on the requirements it will give incorrect results on some data sets, see my answer. Also note that you could drop the loop by using `containsAll()`.

Comment: @TimB I appreciate your comment. The answer given above satisfies the OPs requirement. It is not based around all possible issues which could occur in relation to data structures. Given the information the OP has presented, the answer, in my opinion, is sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

To check if your an item of `list1` is in `list2` you could use this code:

```
 ArrayList<Integer> list1 = new ArrayList<>();
 ArrayList<Integer> list2 = new ArrayList<>();

 //Adding some object to the list here 

 int yourIndex = 1;

 if(list2.contains(list1.get(yourIndex)))
 {
     //do what you want
 }
```

Comment: While this may solve his problem depending on the requirements it will give incorrect results on some data sets, see my answer. Also note that you could drop the loop by using containsAll()